# how to conver a memory address in little endian format through python struct module

Tags: python, endianness, pack

I need to convert a memory address to the following notation: uint32 little endian (DCBA)
I found the struct module online, but I can't figure out which parameter to use to get what I need.
For example I need to convert this:0x8048424 and get in output this: \x24\x84\x04\x08
I tried this already, but the output omits the sequence \x24:

```
import struct
x= struct.pack('<L',0x8048424 )
print(x)
```

But it delete x24, what is the correct value to pass to pack for my purpose?

Comment: It doesn't, it just prints a `$` instead, because thats a printable character.

Comment: @tkausl there is something that i can do for solve this problem?